# Using VPS to create VPN and using the local Ip address to send (Secure) a get/websocket request

Tags: centos, frontend, vpn, vps, openvpn

So I have a VPS (Cent Os 7) and using openvpn I created VPN having an address of 10.0.8.1 now on my front end I connected to VPN using openvpn after connecting I get access to websocket on 10.0.8.1 but its not secure I want access to wss on the same address. I have also tried using a secure domain name to connect but it still fails I can only connect it with either http or ws and not with https or wss

Comment: VPS... VPN...it seems that 'virtual private' can be excluded from the equation in order to simplify it a bit. So you have a S (server) which has a N (network - private...)
If all runs inside of something that a decent somone has created and secured, you wouldn't need to have too too much 'security' or encryption on your connection.

You issue seem to be that you need to actually use/configure encryption on yor websocket. This means get a ssl certificate/key combo... change WS config in order for it to run WSS (like http and httpS, same deal)

Answer (score 0):

This is very trivial as far as a question but all in all, without telling you how to perform anything in details - the question is WWAAAYYY too broad to even consider answering without unevitably creating more questions than solving a problem or helping you.

You need to add cryptography to your websocket server, same as a web server is able to run in HTTP**S** mode rather than unencrypted. I'm sure you can see the similarity between both abreviations of the respective protocols and how they are different from their original, unencrypted/vulnerable default configuration.

http -> https
ws -> wss

Start reading on adding a SSL certificate to your websocket server config and then you will have a WSS connection - if all goes well of course!

I believe in you

p.s. - this is not the type of question that is very well received by the majority of the community. It is too broad to be of any interrest  to anyone.A complete, well-built, comprehensive answer isn't something that fits within the boudaries of most community members as there is WAY too many variables and unknowns here. Anything will most likely create more questions (of this quality) than help you or anyone else. You lack basic knowledge in order to construct a question that doesn't sound anything other than 'i need a full tutorial'. Community doesn't provide tutorials, custom solutions or anything that resssembles a full product/service. We rather help solve smaller, more precise and clear issues that pop up day to day in the field. Generally, when someone **"talks the talk"**, it implies that the bases are covered and an issue arose. For now, you must learn to **"walk the walk"** i suppose.

Everyone wore the same shoes at some point or another and good memory comes from remembering such stuff from when we started playing with the wall socket angry pixies!

Cheers!